# AP + BQ = 1 (Euclidean algorithm)

Tags: polynomials, roots, euclidean-algorithm

If $P, Q \in K[X]$ with no roots in common, then there exist $A, B \in K[X]$ such that $AP + BQ = 1 .$ It should be done with the Euclidean algorithm applied on $P$ and $Q$ but I don't know how to do that so that the existence of $A$ and $B$ can be proved.

Comment: You mean, of course, that $\;K\;$ is a **field** ...right?

Comment: $K$ an _algebraically closed_ field; or no roots in common _in an extension field of $K$_? Otherwise $K = {\mathbb R}, P=Q=X^2+1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Do you know what the _Extended_ Euclidean Algorithm gives you?

Comment: Well, the Theorem says: "If P and Q are polynomials with no roots in common, then there exist two other polynomials A and B such that AP + BQ = 1. "

Comment: Not quite, just that it gives the inverse, but not how can it be applied in this case

Comment: Gurterz edit in a pair of polynomials, with ordinary integer coefficients, and I will show you.... the overall proposition can be proved on its own, but I think knowing how to do the algorithm is a real help.

Comment: have common factro (and common root) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273572/highest-common-factor-of-two-polynomials/2273666#2273666

Comment: coprime: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264934/find-the-ideal-generated-by-two-elements-in-a-euclidean-domain/2265008#2265008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The claim is false if $K$ is not a field:*

Take $P=2$ and $Q=2X$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$. If $AP + BQ = 1$ then $2A(0)=1$, which cannot happen in $\mathbb Z$.

*The claim is false if $K$ is not an algebraically closed field:*

Take $P=X^2+1$ and $Q=X(X^2+1)$ in $\mathbb R[X]$. If $AP + BQ = 1$ then $(A+BX)(X^2+1)=1$, which cannot happen in $\mathbb R[X]$ since $X^2+1$ is not a unit.

*The claim is true if $K$ is an algebraically closed field.*

In this case, $P$ and $Q$ have no roots in common iff $\gcd(P,Q)=1$ because the irreducibles in $K[X]$ are exactly the polynomials of degree $1$ when $K$ is an algebraically closed field. The claim then follows from the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.